# How to compare against fields that are `null` (empty)?

Tags: php, cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I have a table in a CakePHP 3 application called `downloads` which has a column called `master`. The field type is set to `TINYINT(1)`

I can find any records where `downloads.master == 1` like this:

```
$query = $this->Downloads->find()->where(['master' => true]);
```

But Cake won't let me query for ones where `downloads.master !== 1`. None of these work, and all return an empty array/object when the query is executed:

```
$query = $this->Downloads->find()->where(['master' => false]);
$query = $this->Downloads->find()->where(['master' => 0]);
$query = $this->Downloads->find()->where(['master' => null]);
$query = $this->Downloads->find()->where(['master' => '']);
```

What do you use as the condition to make this possible? My thinking was that it should be `false` since that's the opposite to `true`, but as with most things in CakePHP 3 they like to make it more complicated than necessary...

I've examined the records in my table using phpMyAdmin and there are indeed both records where `master == 1` and `master == null` so it's not a case of there's zero results to return.

Comment: By 'none of these work' what do you mean? Is it throwing an error? Have you checked the SQL being generated?

Comment: Dont allow boolean values to be null in the first place. Bool means by definition either true or false, nothing else - ever. That will resolve your problem by design, without any need for any change :) If you need null ("default nothing") or more, use tinyint(2) and some ENUM solution instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A column being `NULL` is not the same as being `0` (ie `false`-ish from the point of view of the ORM in case of a `boolean`-ish column type). If you want to compare against `NULL`, then you must issue a query with `IS NULL`, which is a SQL/DBMS requirement, not a CakePHP requirement.

CakePHP however requires you to be specific about what you want to do, as passing `null` does not neccesarily have to mean that you want to compare against SQL `NULL`, depending on the context.

Long story short, use the `IS` operator:

```
where(['master IS' => null])
```

Similarly use `IS NOT` for a negated condition. You can also pass user input as the value, the ORM will test the value and convert the `IS` and `IS NOT` operators into `=` and `!=` respectively in case a non-`null` value is being passed.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Automatic IS NULL Creation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatic-is-null-creation)**